# Reduce an array based on more than one value

Tags: reactjs, reduce

I am working on a tool to highlight the given word in a text. it is working but it is not case-sensitive, I want to check Capitalize, Uppercase and lowercase version of the word in my Reduce function:

Here is my code:

```
textItem.split(searchText)
.reduce((strArray, currentValue, currentIndex) => (
   currentIndex === 0 ?
   ([...strArray, currentValue]) :
   ([...strArray,
   <mark key={currentIndex}>{searchText}</mark>,
   currentValue])
   ),
[]);
```

unfortunately, adding another split and reduce after the first once is not working for me and I think the reason is the  component within the reduce function!

How can I check Capitalize, Uppercase and lowercase version of the word in the text?

Answer (score 2):

If it is a string why you don’t use String#replace? Like

```
let text = 'Lorem Ipsum lattim rand stack ipsum';
const searchText = 'ipsum';
text = text.replace(new RegExp(searchText, 'gi'), match => { 
           return <mark>{match}</mark>;
});
```

The options `gi` is to make the research case insensitive and for all occurrences.